# How to fix the position of searchbar us

Tags: ios, swift

I'm try to build search function using tutorial from https://www.thorntech.com/2016/01/how-to-search-for-location-using-apples-mapkit/
I need to change his code
because as you can see from the picture if I do `navigationitem.titleview` the plus button disappears. I want to use searchbar when I searching but I couldn't find a way to do it

```
 let searchBar = resultSearchController!.searchBar
        searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchBar.placeholder = "Search for places"
        navigationItem.titleView = resultSearchController?.searchBar
        resultSearchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        resultSearchController?.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
        definesPresentationContext = true
        locationSearchTable.mapView = mapView
        locationSearchTable.handleMapSearchDelegate = self
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
navigationItem.titleView = resultSearchController?.searchBar
```

Try

```
navigationItem.searchController = resultSearchController
```